# Datatables fixed width issue in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to use fixed width in Datatables, but in Safari and Chrome the first column i.e. checkbox column is messed up and is merged with the 2nd column. Here's a example:

http://bufle.com/dtable/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html

Comment: How about show us the code here ?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has `<th style="width: 2%">` for the first column header and `<td style="width: 2%">` for the first column in the body rows. Remove those width attributes.

Comment: +1 that's the cause - but actually the first th width was set at 0px :)

Comment: @wirey It is in the rendered DOM but not the base HTML (as seen with view source).